# How to search in django ManyToMany admin edit

Tags: python, django

I have a ManyToMany field in django that I want to update in the admin dashboard. It looks like this: [image]

However there are 200+ entries here and I would like to search through them in order to update them (instead of scrolling). When I hit a key on keyboard to filter through the list, it searches in the order of the string and doesn't look for substrings. So if I type in the word "holding" I get the first entry in the photo because it starts with an H. How can I change this so that it searches substrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) on the field for a nicer widget that has search.

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
   # ...
   filter_horizontal = ('the_name_of_that_field',)
```